# WPF Button event not firing while Grid have PreviewMouseMove set

Tags: c#, wpf

I have button on the Grid that does not detects PreviewMouseLeftDown click event.
After some testing I figured that the problem is in `<Grid PreviewMouseMove="onMouseMove" >`

If I remove PreviewMouseMove="onMouseMove" part, then MouseDown event is detected, but i need that line of code, since I also have to detect mouse position inside that grid only.

XAML:

```
<Grid PreviewMouseMove="onMouseMove" Background="Transparent">
    <ItemsControl Name="btnTableImageList">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding Content}"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                        Width="{Binding Width}"
                        Tag="{Binding Tag}"
                        Margin="{Binding Margin}"
                        Background="{Binding Background}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown ="tblButton_MouseDown"
                        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp ="tblButton_MouseUp"
                        Click="ClickHandlerTableBtn"
                        TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Any idea is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you get an answer to this, I'm afraid you are going down the rabbit hole! You should learn about Commands and maybe refine your understanding about MVVM in general. If you feel you don't need that for your project, WPF might not be the right choice. The Bindings look very suspicious to me, especially the Binding of Tag to Tag...

Comment: @themightylc Can you please explain what is wrong with "Binding Tag"? I am using it for some data that is loaded from database, and since Buttons are generated during runtime, this is the way I am assigning data to certain button properties.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with it. It is impossible to explain the concept of MVVM in a few words. But try to answer this yourself: What is the Binding Source and if it's an class you designed yourself, then why did you call the source Property "Tag"?

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to achieve something like a gallery, maybe with pictures where you can move the pictures with your mouse but also something happens when you click on them, correct?
Why would you need to Handle the Click Event, as well as MouseUp and MouseDown? Why does your Button have to be a Button?

Comment: to clarify: it's awesome you're trying to make something and WPF is a great framework. I love it. But I can spot one key problem in your second line of XAML and that is, your ItemsControl does not have an ItemsSource. Which means you must fill it programatically. Which means you create the "Content" Objects programatically. Which leads to the question why the Data in "Tag" is not in the Content already. I recommend you take a few hours and watch a few Videos on MVVM, especially the MVVM light toolkit. http://www.mvvmlight.net/ It can't be done in five minutes but it is well worth your time.

Comment: I am designing POS system (I designed few before, and they are commercialy successful) but I never used WPF before(used WinForms for previous work). I am trying to achive that admin user can left click on form and code will autogenerate new button (doesn't have to be a button, it can be an image, but for now I am testing with a button). Then user can move that button wherever he likes (within grid), and click again to set that button down. Then a new windows open with some images and data pulled from database, where admin user can set some properties.

Comment: That same button is also available to ordinary user, but  he can click on the button and he can click and drag from one button to another to move data that is loaded on first button to the second one of his choice. He cannot change data, only access it or move it. Thank you for the link, I will check it out.

Comment: What are you doing in your onMouseMove event handler? Please post some code that can be used to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Now that I know what you are trying to do, I will double down on my recommendation: learn how to correctly use MVVM. What you are trying to achieve is very easy with WPF when you know how to do it MVVM-style and can be frustratingly difficult if you apply your WinForms knowledge. Just try trust me on this and don't do learning-by-doing with this. I've been using WPF professionally for almost 7 years now and I loved Databinding and just jumped in after I thought I got the gist of it, but today would not repeat *one single line of code* from my first attempts. That's both XAML and code-behind.

Comment: @mm8 Thank you for your effort, but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with themightylc, but also understand you... WPF and MVVM are not so "easy" to get used to, I do it for a year more or less, and still have a lot to learn.
In that kind of situation I only could advise you to read some tutorials about WPF, DataBinding and ObservableCollection and ViewModel (these are the keywords you need to know).
1) Create a ViewModel where you can define a ObservableCollection, ObservableCollection is kind of list, but using it you can update your View (almost) automaticaly.so when you launch your application, you will read the list of buttons you need to display, then add them to the ObservableCollection

for your tests will be something like that :

```
Button button1=new Button();
Button button2=new Button();

//define all dimensions/parameters of your button

MyObservableCollection.Add(button1);
MyObservableCollection.Add(button2);
```

Then in XAML you just need to specify the ItemsSource of ItemsControls(MyObservableCollection). doing like that you don't need anymore all description of buttons inside.

Then when you click to add a button(in your case), you just need to make in code behind something like

```
Button newButton=new Button(); 
newButton.Height=defaultHeight...//width, background etc...
MyObservableCollection.Add(newButton);
```

again, just for advise if WPF/MVVM is new to you, I would advise to begin with easier samples, make a small listview with simple objects inside, or a listbox.

Could also advise you these websites :
wpf-tutorial.com
www.wpftutorial.net

Answer (score 0):

At the end this is actually working properly.

For test I have set up a label, and in MouseMove event i am sending Mouse Position to that label,`lblCoord.Content = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);`

In case of MouseClick I am sending `lblCoord.Content="MouseClick";`

And in case of MouseDown I am sending `lblCoord.Content="MouseDown";`.

I can see mouse coordinates in lblCoord, I can see MouseClick, but it never displayed MouseDown.

However, if i call MessageBox inside MouseDown event, everything works. So i guess that XAML `<Grid> PreviewMouseMove="onMouseMove"` works even when I am not moving mouse so it is sending coords to a Label all the time and overwrites `lblCoord.Content="MouseDown";` faster than I am able to see it.

The answer to this question is: Don't work with WPF and expect WinForms results...
Thanks to everybody for their time and effort!